# Async await how to use return values

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a windows service that I have inherited from another developer, it runs very slow and has numerous slow call to the eBay API. I wish to speed it up without too much refactoring.

I've just started to look at using c# async/await to try to get some of these slow call to run async. 
Here's what i'm trying to achieve:

I have a 1 very busy method that makes lots of calls as below:

```
getProducts
getCategories
getVehicles
getImages
```

My thoughts were that I could simply change the methods to `async` and add `Task<T>` to the return type as below:

```
public async Task<String> ProcessAdditionalProductDetialsAsync(ItemType oItem)
{
    String additionalProductDetails = string.Empty;

    if (oItem.ItemSpecifics.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (NameValueListType nvl in oItem.ItemSpecifics)
        {                  
            if (nvl.Value.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string s in nvl.Value)
                {
                    additionalProductDetails += "<li><strong>" + nvl.Name + ":</strong>&nbsp;" + s + "</li>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return additionalProductDetails;
}
```

Then call them with await:

```
Task<String> additionalProductDetials = ebayPartNumbers.ProcessAdditionalProductDetialsAsync(item);
Task<PartNumberCollection> partNumberCollection = ebayPartNumbers.ProcessPartNumbersAsync(item); 


await Task.WhenAll(partNumberCollection, additionalProductDetials);
```

How do I get hold of the returned types so I can use them?  I have tried just using `partNumberCollection` but it only has the `await` properties available.

Comment: The compiler should be giving you a warning about using `async` without `await` in `ProcessAdditionalProductDetialsAsync`. Is this your actual code or is it really doing an `await`? Where does the eBay API come in?

Comment: Yes the compiler does warn that this method has no await but the await is in the parent method.

Comment: You should pay attention to the compiler warning; there should be an `await` *in that method* if it's `async`. If you want to execute code on a background thread, use `Task.Run`; if you want to do I/O (i.e., the eBay API), it should use naturally-asynchronous methods.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) property on Task class:

```
await Task.WhenAll(partNumberCollection, additionalProductDetials);

var partNumberCollectionResult = partNumberCollection.Result;
var additionalProductDetialsResult = additionalProductDetials.Result;
```

Comment: You should use `await` instead of `Result` to avoid wrapping exceptions in an `AggregateException`.

Answer (score 17):

If the task returned by `Task.WhenAll` has completed, that means all of the tasks that you passed to it have completed too. That in turn means that you can use the [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx) property of each task, with no risk of it blocking.

```
string details = additionalProductDetials.Result;
```

Alternatively, you could await the tasks, for consistency with other async code:

```
string details = await additionalProductDetials;
```

Again, this is guaranteed not to block - and if you later remove the `Task.WhenAll` for some reason (e.g. you're happy to use the details to kick off another task before you've got the part number collection) then you don't need to change the code.

Answer (score 11):

Your `async` method lacks of `await` operators and will run synchronously. while you are calling non blocking API you could use `Task.Run()` to do cpu-bound work on background thread.

```
public async Task<String> ProcessAdditionalProductDetialsAsync(ItemType oItem)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        String additionalProductDetails = string.Empty;

        if (oItem.ItemSpecifics.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (NameValueListType nvl in oItem.ItemSpecifics)
            {
                if (nvl.Value.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string s in nvl.Value)
                    {
                        additionalProductDetails += "<li><strong>" + nvl.Name + ":</strong>&nbsp;" + s + "</li>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return additionalProductDetails;
    });
}
```

and get result

```
var detail = await ProcessAdditionalProductDetialsAsync(itemType);
var result = ProcessAdditionalProductDetialsAsync(itemType).Result;
```

Comment: The parent method that calls this is marked with async and uses the await Task.WhenAll, doesn't this then run the method above async?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public async Task<String> ProcessAdditionalProductDetialsAsync(ItemType oItem) { 
    String additionalProductDetails = await Task.Run(() => {
       if (oItem.ItemSpecifics.Count > 0) {
          foreach (NameValueListType nvl in oItem.ItemSpecifics) { 
             if (nvl.Value.Count > 0) {
                 string retval = String.Empty;

                 foreach (string s in nvl.Value) {
                     retval += "<li><strong>" 
                       + nvl.Name + ":</strong>&nbsp;" + s + "</li>";
                 }
             }
          }
       }
       return retval;
     }
     return additionalProductDetails;
 }
```

Usage:

```
private async void GetAdditionalProductDetailsAsync(Action<string> callback) {
   string apd = await ProcessAdditionalProductDetialsAsync();
   callback(apd);
}

private void AdditionalProductDetailsRetrieved(string apd) {
    // do anything with apd
}
```